# Android ActionBar text shows

Tags: android, android-actionbar

Problem:

Can anyone please explain the cause for this? 
The toolbar text is not properly shown.

Tried:

1. Tried setting the actionbar text in activity, switching fragment, from menu option method, everywhere
2. Tried managing the action menu elements

Thanks!

[image: App Screenshot]

```
TOOLBAR LAYOUT    

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar android:id="@+id/toolbar_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    app:titleTextColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    android:elevation="7dp"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" />

MENU LAYOUT

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_search"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_search_white_24px"
        app:showAsAction="always"
        android:title="Search"/>
</menu>
```

[image]

Comment: Text might be too long

Comment: No, it appears at times, and disappears.

Comment: Show your XML layout.

Comment: @Bryan I've updated it.

Comment: can you show how you are adding magnify icon? any menu XML?

Comment: @snachmsm please see

Comment: I don't see nothing suspicious, probably there is smth wrong in Java code... also you may check the _Show layout bounds_ option in _Developer settings_ of device/emulator, then paste a screen

Comment: @snachmsm much thanks! in advance.

Comment: I don't idea still... show some Java code, it will be best to inspect this. Especially how you are setting this title (and paste whole `String` if you can)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130639/discussion-between-abhinav-jordiie-das-and-snachmsm).